# javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException in jira plugin

Tags: email, jira, jira-plugin

My email sending stuff was working fine before i executed atlas-clean. Now, i am not able send email from my created scheduler service and raising an error as below:

```
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: smtp
at javax.mail.Session.getService(Session.java:798)
at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:720)
at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:660)
at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:640)
at com.crawco.jira.plugin.Reports.DailyReportService.execute(DailyReportService.java:449)
at com.atlassian.sal.jira.scheduling.JiraPluginSchedulerService.run(JiraPluginSchedulerService.java:94)
at com.atlassian.jira.service.JiraServiceContainerImpl.run(JiraServiceContainerImpl.java:61)
at com.atlassian.jira.service.ServiceRunner.execute(ServiceRunner.java:47)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:195)
at com.atlassian.multitenant.quartz.MultiTenantThreadPool$MultiTenantRunnable.run(MultiTenantThreadPool.java:72)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
```

What can be the cause ?

I have already included below stuff in pom.xml -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
   <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Enable mail logging in JIRA to better understand what is happening. See [Logging email protocol details](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Logging+email+protocol+details) on the Atlassian site.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments guys.

I just found, have to remove java.mail and activation dependencies from atlassian-plugin.xml as these libraries already come along with JIRA. So after that, it works fine and got email working.